# From where does the value of argc and argv comes in the main function c++

Tags: c++

I'm new to c++ and I've seen many c++ compilers automatically pass int argc,char* argv as parameters in main function but where are they defined?
A little curious to know about.

Comment: Interesting question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

These are typically supplied by the shell, or more specifically, the parent process. That is the parent process can decide which, if any, parameters to pass through. These show up in `argc`/`argv`. See the [`exec`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/execv) family of functions for examples of how this looks from the parent process perspective. There's also kernel versions of same for launching a process as well.

They're specifically defined and ultimately provided by the operating system and it's inter-process mechanics. This is part of the [C++ standard that defines the `main()` function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function).

This mechanism is inherited from the C version of same, and that's largely a byproduct of how UNIX itself was designed since C and UNIX were produced in tandem.

Answer (score 6):

Please read a good [C++ programming book](https://www.stroustrup.com/programming.html), then see [this C++ reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp) and some C++ standard like [n3337](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) or better.

Your compiler (such as [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/)) does not add `argc` and `argv` parameters to `main`. With `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` it is checking that `main` has these arguments (but you could define `int main(void)` or `int main(int argc, char**argv, char**environ)` on Linux). What is important is the signature of `main`, not the exact name of the arguments (just their type and number).

Your operating system (e.g. Linux and its [kernel](http://kernel.org/)) is passing these to your `main`. On Linux, a program is started by [execve(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) and that system call passes argument to `main`. Technically, the initial layout of the call stack is specified in the ABI. Some [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) initialization code is calling `main` (and static constructors). That initialization code is written in assembler. Read a good [OS textbook](https://pages.cs.wisc.edu/%7Eremzi/OSTEP/).

Sometimes, C++ is used in a freestanding mode. Then, there is no `main` and *other conventions* apply. A typical example is when you code an operating system kernel in C++ (see [OSDEV](https://osdev.org/) for examples)

Since [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), the Linux [kernel](https://kernel.org/), and [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) are free software, you are allowed to download their source code and study it (and later improve it). See also [LinuxFromScratch](https://linuxfromscratch.org/).

Study -for inspiration- the source code of existing C++ open source projects like [Qt](https://qt.io/), [FLTK](https://fltk.org/), [RefPerSys](http://refpersys.org/) etc. For *RefPerSys* contact me by email to `basile@starynkevitch.net`

Answer (score 1):

> I'm new to c++ and I've seen many c++ compilers automatically pass int argc,char* argv as parameters in main function but where are they defined?

They’re part of the C and C++ standards. Exactly how they’re provided to the `main()` function will depend on the operating system. In Unix-likesystems, for example, a combination of `fork()` and some version of `exec()` are used to create a new process and then load and execute your program in the context of that new process, with the arguments to the new program passed along. Other operating systems will start new processes other ways, but the `argc` and `argv` parameters will still come from the program that launched your program, whether that’s a command-oriented shell, some GUI desktop manager, or something else.